# Command to close window from Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I have some scripts to do some work for me on Windows 7, and one issue I have is that my most used script lives on a flash drive, clears out the Drivers folder, then opens the Drivers folder for me automatically. Is there any way to have it close the original Windows Explorer window where I clicked the icon? I can't put a shortcut on my desktop because the flash drive letter changes a lot

Comment: Are you open to the script being a power shell script or must it be a batch script?

Comment: I don't know about Windows 7, but on XP you can go to Disk Management and assign a drive letter to a flash drive while it is plugged-in and afterwards it will always be assigned that drive letter when you plug it in again (assuming the letter is not in use by something else at the time).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I would much rather it be the regular .BAT or .CMD script as it should run on Windows 2000 or higher

Comment: @martineau Yes, 7 and Vista can as well; my issue is that this will be in other computers as well, and sometimes I have 3 or 4 other drives plugged in on USB that I scan for as well (I work in a computer shop)

Comment: @Luke: In that case, you could use Disk Management to assign a "Drive Path" to the flash drive which would make it always appear as the contents of specific folder on the C: drive. This requires that you first create an empty NTFS folder to assign to the drive after you plug it in.

Comment: @martineau But again, I put it into other computers. I need the script to always run on the drive, and it's easiest to open the drive up then double click it to run

Comment: Luke: OK, then maybe your script could begin by executing this [free program](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/17732.html) which closes _all_ open Explorer windows -- which is overkill but might be acceptable -- only thing is I don't know if it'll work on Win7...

Comment: @martineau That would work, except I have other Explorer windows open. +1 for that program though

Comment: @Luke: A problem with multiple Explorer windows open is identifying the one used launch the script. Too bad Microsoft disabled autorun for usb drives in Windows 7 because with that you wouldn't need to open an Explorer window to run the script on the drive. Any chance you could put this stuff on a CD/DVD?

Comment: @martineau The data changes about 5 times per day

Comment: @Luke: I've read that special U3 usb flash drives can still autorun stuff on when one is plugged in under Win7 (as well as earlier versions). However U3 was designed for portable apps which means your script and/or programs run from one can't change the registry or system files on the HD -- which might pose a problem depending on what you're doing.

Comment: @martineau Unfortunately, it's a Kingston, but either way that wouldn't work for me. I do appreciate your help though